# sql: Getting 3 highest values from table in column format

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table(lets call it mytable) with the below structure. The table records close to 1 Million rows everyday.

```
id      date      timestamp  licenseid   storeid    deviceid    value
1     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0add      52
2     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0add      54
3     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0add      53
4     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0001       1         0add      54
5     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0002       1         0add      59
6     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0003       1         0add      62
7     2015-06-12   17:36:21   lic0004       1         0add      55
8     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0001       1         0bdd      53
9     2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0002       1         0bdd      52
10    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0003       1         0bdd      52
11    2015-06-12   17:36:15   lic0004       1         0bdd      50
12    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0002       1         0bdd      54
13    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0003       1         0bdd      54
14    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0004       1         0bdd      55
15    2015-06-12   17:36:33   lic0005       1         0bdd      60
```

I need to use the same data above and fetch data as below. What sql query should I use to get the below output but I only want the three highest values with the corresponding device. I know I need to use pivot but I am having difficulties framing the right query

```
id   date      timestamp   deviceid  storeid  deviceid1  deviceid2   deviceid3  value1   value2   value3  
1  2015-06-12   17:36:15     0add      1        lic001     lic002     lic003      52       54       53     
2  2015-06-12   17:36:21     0add      1        lic002     lic003     lic004      59       62       55
3  2015-06-12   17:36:15     0bdd      1        lic001     lic002     lic003      53       52       52      
4  2015-06-12   17:36:33     0bdd      1        lic002     lic004     lic005      54       55       60
```

For the last row the query could either return lic002 or lic003 as both values are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If acceptable to you, the easiest way is probably to use `group_concat()` and `substring_index()`:

```
select min(id) as id, date, timestamp, storeid,
       substring_index(group_concat(device order by value desc), ',', 3) as devices,
       substring_index(group_concat(value order by value desc), ',', 3) as values
from mytable t
group by date, timestamp, storeid;
```

This puts the three values into a single column.  You could actually then split them into separate columns if you like.

Otherwise, you need to enumerate the values and that gets complicated -- with a single query, you need either a subquery/non-equijoin (probably really expensive on your size of data) or variables.

Comment: "Otherwise..." -- It's not too bad if you use the [technique in my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#top_n_in_each_group).

Comment: @RickJames  . . . The specific code in your blog is not safe because you have multiple variable assignments in a `select`, and the logic depends on the order of evaluation of the expressions.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  However, if this version doesn't meet the OP's needs, then there are other methods.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why do we need the min(id)  here? Also I see that the query works to an extent but it is not restricting it to 3 values and the separator also cannot be changed from , to say something like a |.

Comment: @theo . . . `min(id)` seemed like what you wanted for the first column, but I think I misread the values.  Something like `@rn := @rn + 1 as id` may be what you want.  You can change the delimiter by using the `separator` keyword in `group_concat()`.